# Issue with Order By with FOR XML in T-sql (The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-order-by

```
select a.Hall, a.Title, 
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + '[' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Hour, b.StartFilm))  
  + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Minute, b.StartFilm)) 
  + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Hour, b.EndTime))  
  + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Minute, b.EndTime)) 
  + ']' 
FROM (select c.Name as Hall, b.Title, 
    Convert(time,a.StartFilmTime) as StartFilm,  
    Convert(time,a.EndFilmTime) as EndTime
  from FilmSchedule a 
    left join Film b on a.FilmId = b.Id 
    left join Room c on a.RoomId = c.Id 
  where a.ApproveStatus = 1 and a.Status = 1 
        and CONVERT(date, a.StartFilmTime) =  '05-06-2015'
) b 
Where a.Hall = b.Hall and a.Title = b.Title 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As ShowTime  
from (select c.Name as Hall, b.Title, 
  Convert(time,a.StartFilmTime) as StartFilm,  
  Convert(time,a.EndFilmTime) as EndTime
  from FilmSchedule a 
  left join Film b on a.FilmId = b.Id 
  left join Room c on a.RoomId = c.Id 
  where a.ApproveStatus = 1 and a.Status = 1 
     and CONVERT(date, a.StartFilmTime) =  '05-06-2015'
  Order by a.StartFilmTime
) a 
group by a.Hall, a.Title
```

I get the error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Help please! (I have used `FOR XML`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your query does use `FOR XML` (for the [`GROUP_CONCAT` workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/314291)), you are applying the order by outside of the derived table that uses `FOR XML`, hence the error.

Given that you aren't including start date directly in the final select (although you are composing it as part of the `STUFF ShowTime` column), you also can't `ORDER BY StartFilm` in the final `GROUP BY` either, as the column would otherwise need to be included in the `GROUP BY` or as an aggregated column.

What you can do is move the `ORDER BY` into the STUFF and then order by the derived column `ShowTime` (since your query only runs for one given day, and StartFilmTime is the first part of the `STUFFED` composed column).

At the same time, I would DRY up the repetition on the derived table with a CTE:

```
WITH cteFiltered AS
    (select c.Name as Hall, b.Title, 
        Convert(time,a.StartFilmTime) as StartFilm,  
        Convert(time,a.EndFilmTime) as EndTime
    from FilmSchedule a 
        left join Film b on a.FilmId = b.Id 
        left join Room c on a.RoomId = c.Id 
    where a.ApproveStatus = 1 and a.Status = 1 
          and CONVERT(date, a.StartFilmTime) =  '05-06-2015'
    )
select 
    a.Hall, 
    a.Title, 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + '[' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Hour, b.StartFilm))  
    + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Minute, b.StartFilm)) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Hour, b.EndTime))  
    + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(Minute, b.EndTime)) 
    + ']' 
        FROM
            cteFiltered b
        Where 
            a.Hall = b.Hall and a.Title = b.Title 
        order by b.StartFilm -- ***
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As ShowTime  
from 
    cteFiltered a 
group by a.Hall, a.Title
order by ShowTime; -- *** Hour is first (assuming 24H format) and only one day
```

Comment: One other thing to note is that the performance of your query will hurt for large tables because `CONVERT(date, a.StartFilmTime) =  '05-06-2015'` isn't SARGable for an index on `StartFilmTime`. Suggest you change this to `a.StartFilmTime >= '05-06-2015' and a.StartFilmTime < '06-06-2015'` or similar.